# Multivariate linear regression - optimizing one coefficient at a time

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

I have a few questions about solving the multivariate linear regression problem:

1. What is the most popular numerical method used to get the coefficients from multivariate linear regression? I assume it is not the exact implementation of the analytical solution, but I also see a huge memory usage explosion in python sklearn in the process of calculation.
2. Suppose I optimize the coefficients one at a time, then repeat the above process until convergence. This is basically doing coordinate descent on the regression coefficients. Is there any formal proof or counter example that the above procedure will/won't converge to the optimal solution?

Comment: By "multivariate" do you mean having multiple outcome/response variables with a set of predictors, or simply having more than one predictor for a single outcome variable?

Comment: Another possibility is to fit a minimal portion of the data, and then using those fitted parameters as initial estimates add in more data, and repeat until all data is used.